# Using mobile navigation breakpoint on desktop viewport w/o editing breakpoints

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, sass, navbar

I have a responsive site with common breakpoints set up in SCSS as mixins. I would like to force the mobile breakpoint (collapsed nav) on a desktop viewport for only a single page out of the entire site.

My first instinct was to extend the existing navbar class into a forced-mobile class which I would append to the existing navbar class on that page and include a different breakpoint mixin for the forced class so that all screen sizes >= 1024px would show the collapsed mobile menu.

Would this be the best practice for this situation? Or is there a simpler, more DRY technique that would display the collapsed mobile navbar for that page only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I would approach something like this by adding a class to the body tag of the page in question, then use that new class to target the navbar on just that one page.

I can't picture what you are describing about extending your existing navbar class so not sure if my suggestion is an improvement.

**Update**

What I was thinking of was:

**Create a _nav.scss partial file** with your common nav styling

```
// _nav.scss

    // SCSS partial with common nav styling
```

Then **import this partial into your base SCSS file**, with media queries as needed

```
    // default nav on most pages, adjust breakpoint as req'd
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        .current-nav{
            @import 'nav';  
        }
    }


    // nav on .forced-mobile page only
    @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
        .forced-mobile .current-nav{
            @import 'nav';  
        }

   }
```

**HTML structure**

```
<body>
 <!-- default for most pages -->
    ...
    <div.current-nav>
        ... 
    </div>

</body>


<body class="forced-mobile">
 <!-- forced-mobile page -->
    ...
    <div.current-nav>
        ... 
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Would the new body class just need a new breakpoint and then state all the mobile breakpoint properties of the navbar? My navbar extend idea resembles that, where the current navbar class is the extendee and my new forced-mobile nav class simply uses the current mobile properties yet only functions on desktop sizes and above. Then I would just apply the forced-mobile nav class after the current, so something like <nav class="current-nav forced-mobile-nav">

Comment: Hey @H.E.Pennypacker, please see my update above. I can't picture if my suggestion is an improvement on your approach or not. Cheers!

Comment: This worked a whole lot smoother than my plan of attack with much less edits. Thanks, David!

Comment: Excellent, I'm pleased this was helpful @H.E.Pennypacker